# Xampp goes to public directory when I go to localhost/

Tags: xampp, redirect

## This is a clean xampp install on my computer

And when I go to `localhost/` xampp goes to `/public/public/public/ect...`

I have no idea why, i have done nothing except deleting all files in htdocs folder. (and httpd.conf is normal, nothing there...)

And yes, I have tried to reinstall xampp...

[image: Xampp is doing this]

I am completely lost.. what is happening?

Comment: Looks like there is some redirection rule running wild. Are you sure you deleted _all_ files? Also hidden ones? Check using `ls -al`, especially look for a dynamic configuration file called ".htaccess".

Comment: Yep, 100% sure, i even deleted the xampp folder in my C:/. btw just reinstalled xampp for the third time, problem is still there... :/

Comment: And you tripple checked that this really is the DocumentRoot oft that host and that there are no rewriting rules in the real host configuration?

Comment: i have yes, i don't get why it keeps doing this. however, i just tried to install MAMP on my pc, and the same thing happens, sooo i guess it's not xampp then.. wow, but what could have caused that??

Comment: `MAMP` on a `PC`? Em...

Comment: I suggest you start by using your browser in an anonymous tab and opening its console. Do a request and see what responses you receive.

Comment: okay, so i solved it now, apparently is was chromes 301 caches that was playing tricks, but thx for the help guys...